# Chart.js Line graph y-axis not starting from 0

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

[image: line graph]
This is my current line graph. The x-axis is just a mock data so hope u guys can overlook the bad data used. As you can see on the y-axis, it is starting from 60 which is not what i want. I have tried `beginAtZero = true` but its not working. I would also like to remove the label `weight` but by simply removing not putting the labels, it would say `undefined`.

Below is the code for the line graph.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2'

function LineChart(datasets) {
  const dataset = datasets.data
  return (
    <div>
      <Line
        data={{
          labels: dataset.map(data=> data.created_at),
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Weight',
            data: dataset.map(data => data.weight),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          }]
        }}
        height = {200}
        options = {{
          resposive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                }
            }]
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default LineChart
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you're using Chart.js version 3, where the `scales` option needs to be defined differently (see [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#stacked-area-chart)).

```
options = {{ 
  resposive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  scales: {
    y: {
      beginAtZero: true          
    }
  }      
}}
```